# JavaFX TreeView hide context menu when tree is empty

Tags: javafx, treeview, contextmenu, javafx-8

I have a TreeView with a context menu, all works except when tree is empty. When tree is empty, I want to prevent show context menu to user.

```
//Set up context menu and menu items
final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
final MenuItem miSubir = new MenuItem("Subir");
final MenuItem miBajar = new MenuItem("Bajar");
final MenuItem miBorrar = new MenuItem("Borrar");

//add events from clic on menu items
miBorrar.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    ...
});

...

//Add menu items to context menu
contextMenu.getItems().add(miSubir);
contextMenu.getItems().add(miBajar);
contextMenu.getItems().add(miBorrar);

//Associate context menu to treeview
treeEjercicios.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
```

When I use Table component, I fix the problem with:

```
row.contextMenuProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty())
        .then((ContextMenu) null)
        .otherwise(contextMenu)
);
```

But I don't know how to apply to use with TreeView or any other alternative?

Comment: I would try the same with the treeCell (if you had provided a SSCCE ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root item is shown, i.e. `tree.setShowRoot(true)`, it can be supposed that when the root item is null the treeview is empty. So we can bind it

```
tree.contextMenuProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when( Bindings.isNull( tree.rootProperty() ) )
        .then( (ContextMenu) null)
        .otherwise( contextMenu )
);
```

Else if the root item is not show, then the tree can be supposed to be empty if this root item has no children, i.e. when `isLeaf()` returns true. In this case the binding will be:

```
tree.contextMenuProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when( tree.getRoot().leafProperty() )
        .then( ( ContextMenu ) null )
        .otherwise( contextMenu )
);
```

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work. And no, root is hidden because I don't want to show in the UI.